# Is it possible to prevent the auto-generate code file being given a namespace generated by a Preprocessed Text Template

Tags: .net, code-generation, t4

When compiling a .tt file, can I specify anywhere in the directive to prevent the auto generated code file from being placed into the My.Templates namespace?

The basic directive:

```
<#@ template language="VB"  #>
```

The auto generated code behind file:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'<auto-generated>
'    This code was generated by a tool.
'    Runtime Version: 10.0.0.0
' 
'    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'    the code is regenerated.
'</auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Namespace My.Templates
    <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating", "10.0.0.0")>  _
    Partial Public Class DriverApplicationToLicensing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify it in the directive, but if you look in the properties of the template in the IDE, you should see a "Custom Tool Namespace" option, which will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

- Select your template (.tt) and cmd ALT+ENTER (right click and "Properties").
- Under "Advanced", properties "Custom Tool Namespace", delete the value if exists
- Select your template (.tt), right click and click on "Run Custom Tool"

Every namespace for the auto generated code should be removed.